# How to not allow a draggable <img> in a div with an existing <img> that is dragged first using javascript? I only want one draggable <img> in a div?

Tags: javascript

How to not allow a draggable  in a div with an existing  that is dragged first using javascript? I only want one draggable  in a div??
my script in dragging and dropping image in a div..

```
function allowDrop(ev) 
    {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }


function drag(ev) 
    {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }


function drop(ev) 
    {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"); 
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `<img draggable="false">`

Comment: I cant.. I need to drag an image to a div....the problem is I want to drag one image only to a single div...

Comment: Can you share your attempt in full? I assume you have already got the regular many images to div working, yes?

Comment: Yes :D .. here is the thing ... I have four div to place a draggable image.. each four div should only contain one image..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.